# How to block java application from sending email during development?

Tags: java, email, smtp, development-environment

My application sends some emails to our customers to warn them about some errors while we process their files. However, I would like to disable this feature, **without altering my code**, for development/test purposes.

Is there any argument to pass to my JVM in order to block it from sending emails ?

Comment: Give it another smtp server? One that does ... nothing. Would that be an option? Or is it hard-coded?

Comment: It's hard-coded for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the SMTP server's hostname is hardcoded in the code, for example:

```
server = "smtp.example.com"
```

You could alter the host file at /etc/hosts to override the DNS lookup. Add this to your hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 smtp.example.com
```

This will prevent your program from interacting with the mail server. Make sure to delete that line when you are done.

Otherwise, if the IP address is what's hardcoded, you can use a firewall. The exact procedure will depend on the operating system you are using. If you're running an OS with a Linux kernel, you can use **iptables** to block that IP address:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT 1 --destination 1.2.3.4 -j REJECT
```

Or, for a more specific rule:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT 1 --destination 1.2.3.4 -p tcp --dport 25 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

Again, remember to change it back when you're done:

```
iptables -D OUTPUT 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the JavaMail provider with [one that "mocks" a real provider,](https://community.oracle.com/blogs/kohsuke/2007/04/26/introducing-mock-javamail-project) just by adding a jar to your classpath. In addition to blocking outbound mail, it allows you to perform unit testing on your application's email functions. [This library](https://java.net/projects/mock-javamail/) was created by Kohsuke Kawaguchi, creator of Hudson/Jenkins.